# how to delete a static object in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build simple painter (i.e. points, lines, circles ...etc) in glut. Each line must have two points of `Point` type, so every time the user enter the left button of the mouse, the chosen command is executed. For drawing a line, I need to track how many times the user click the mouse, so this is what I'v done

```
        if ( command == 1 ){ // drawing a line
            static int count(0); // track click no. 
            static std::vector<Point> p;
            //static Point startPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
            p.push_back(Point(mouseX, mouseY));

            if ( count == 1 ){
                Point endPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
                Point startPoint = p[0];
                shapes->addLine(Line(startPoint, endPoint));
                count = 0;
                p.clear();
            }else{
                count++;
            }
```

I'm using `std::vector` only to use `clear()` so that I can delete `startPoint` which I need it to be static. My question is is there a way to destroy an object without making more lines by using `vector`? I've tried to call the destructor but it didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `unique_ptr<Point>`.  Then you can use `reset` to set or destroy the `Point`:

```
static std::unique_ptr<Point> startPoint;

if (startPoint){
  Point endPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
  shapes->addLine({*startPoint, endPoint});
  startPoint.reset();
} else {
  startPoint.reset(new Point(mouseX,  mouseY));
}
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. I need to read about `unique_ptr` so than I can judge which more simpler mine or your approach. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine. If you're worried about the number of lines then this is a shorter version:

```
if ( command == 1 ){ // drawing a line
    static std::vector<Point> p;
    p.push_back(Point(mouseX, mouseY));
    if (p.size() == 2){
        shapes->addLine(Line(p[0], p[1]));
        p.clear();
    }
}
```

Note however that using less lines is only a good thing if this improves readability. If instead it becomes harder to understand the code then it's a bad idea.

Most code is written only once but read many times... saving time when writing is not such a big deal.

In this specific case in my opinion this shorter version is easier to understand, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those times where something like `std::optional<Point>` would've been nice.

But regarding to the destruction and reconstruction part, placement new can be helpful here:

```
static int count(0);
// ('aligned_storage' requires C++11 and '#include <type_traits>')
static std::aligned_storage<sizeof(Point), alignof(Point)>::type startPointBuffer;
Point& startPoint = *static_cast<Point*>(static_cast<void*>(&startPointBuffer));
if (count == 1) {
    Point endPoint(mouseX, mouseY);
    shapes->addLine(Line(startPoint, endPoint));
    count = 0;
    startPoint.~Point();
} else {
    new (&startPoint) Point(mouseX, mouseY);
    count++;
}
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you but it seems more complicated than my approach. Thanks for the answer though. At least I learned something new.